# How can I get the SID of the current Windows account?

Tags: c#, c++, windows, winapi, sid

I am looking for an easy way to get the SID for the current Windows user account. I know I can do it through WMI, but I don't want to go that route.

Apologies to everybody that answered in C# for not specifying it's C++. :-)

Comment: programming language/environment?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

In Win32, call [GetTokenInformation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa446671.aspx), passing a token handle and the `TokenUser` constant. It will fill in a [TOKEN_USER](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa379634.aspx) structure for you. One of the elements in there is the user's SID. It's a BLOB (binary), but you can turn it into a string by using [ConvertSidToStringSid](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa376399.aspx).

To get hold of the current token handle, use [OpenThreadToken](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa379296(VS.85).aspx) or [OpenProcessToken](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa379295(VS.85).aspx).

If you prefer ATL, it has the [CAccessToken](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-za/cpp/atl/reference/caccesstoken-class?view=msvc-160) class, which has all sorts of interesting things in it.

.NET has the [Thread.CurrentPrinciple](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.currentprincipal.aspx) property, which returns an IPrincipal reference. You can get the SID:

```
IPrincipal principal = Thread.CurrentPrincipal;
WindowsIdentity identity = principal.Identity as WindowsIdentity;
if (identity != null)
    Console.WriteLine(identity.User);
```

Also in .NET, you can use WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent(), which returns the current user ID:

```
WindowsIdentity identity = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent();
if (identity != null)
    Console.WriteLine(identity.User);
```

Comment: Using .NET from Powershell: > [System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent().User.Value

Answer (score 10):

```
ATL::CAccessToken accessToken;
ATL::CSid currentUserSid;
if (accessToken.GetProcessToken(TOKEN_READ | TOKEN_QUERY) &&
    accessToken.GetUser(&currentUserSid))
    return currentUserSid.Sid();
```

Comment: This is very concise.

Answer (score 7):

This should give you what you need:

using System.Security.Principal;

...

var sid = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().User;

The User property of WindowsIdentity returns the SID, per [MSDN Docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.principal.windowsidentity_members.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

[CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/processownersid.aspx) has a few different methods you can try... You didn't mention what languages you wanted a solution in.

If you want to access it via a batch file or something, you can look as PsGetSid by [Sysinternals](http://www.sysinternals.com). It translates SIDs to names and vice versa.

Answer (score 2):

In C# you can use either

`using Microsoft.Win32.Security;`

...

`string username = Environment.UserName + "@" + Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("USERDNSDOMAIN");`

`Sid sidUser = new Sid (username);`

**Or...**

`using System.Security.AccessControl;`

`using System.Security.Principal;`

...

`WindowsIdentity m_Self = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent();`

`SecurityIdentifier m_SID = m_Self.Owner;");`

Answer (score 2):

I found another way to get SID:

```
System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity id = System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent();
string sid = id.User.AccountDomainSid.ToString();
```

Comment: This is the sid of the domain not of the user account
use id.User.ToString() for the user's sid

Answer (score 1):

And in native code:

```
function GetCurrentUserSid: string;

    hAccessToken: THandle;
    userToken: PTokenUser;
    dwInfoBufferSize: DWORD;
    dw: DWORD;

    if not OpenThreadToken(GetCurrentThread, TOKEN_QUERY, True, ref hAccessToken) then
        dw <- GetLastError;
        if dw <> ERROR_NO_TOKEN then
            RaiseLastOSError(dw);

        if not OpenProcessToken(GetCurrentProcess, TOKEN_QUERY, ref hAccessToken) then
            RaiseLastOSError;
    try
        userToken <- GetMemory(1024);
        try
            if not GetTokenInformation(hAccessToken, TokenUser, userToken, 1024, ref dwInfoBufferSize) then
                RaiseLastOSError;
            Result <- SidToString(userToken.User.Sid);
        finally
            FreeMemory(userToken);
    finally
        CloseHandle(hAccessToken);
```

Answer (score 1):

This question is tagged as `c++` And I answer in `c++` language, So I recommend use of ***WMI*** tool :

So, As ***WMI*** commands in `powershell`, bellow command get `SID` of `system-pc1` user :

> ```
> Get-WmiObject win32_useraccount -Filter "name = 'system-pc1'" | Select-Object sid
> ```

First, you need to get current `username` with bellow `code` :

```
char username[UNLEN+1];
DWORD username_len = UNLEN+1;
GetUserName(username, &username_len);
```

Now you can try with `WQL` language and execute this query in `c++` as bellow (in this example , I used of `system-pc1` username in `WQL_WIN32_USERACCOUNT_QUERY` query :

```
#define                 NETWORK_RESOURCE                    "root\\CIMV2"
#define                 WQL_LANGUAGE                        "WQL"
#define                 WQL_WIN32_USERACCOUNT_QUERY         "SELECT * FROM Win32_Useraccount where name='system-pc1'"
#define                 WQL_SID                             "SID"

IWbemLocator            *pLoc = 0;              // Obtain initial locator to WMI to a particular host computer
IWbemServices           *pSvc = 0;              // To use of connection that created with CoCreateInstance()
ULONG                   uReturn = 0;
HRESULT                 hResult = S_OK;         // Result when we initializing
IWbemClassObject        *pClsObject = NULL;     // A class for handle IEnumWbemClassObject objects
IEnumWbemClassObject    *pEnumerator = NULL;    // To enumerate objects
VARIANT                 vtSID = { 0 };          // OS name property

// Initialize COM library
hResult = CoInitializeEx(0, COINIT_MULTITHREADED);
if (SUCCEEDED(hResult))
{
    // Initialize security
    hResult = CoInitializeSecurity(NULL, -1, NULL, NULL, RPC_C_AUTHN_LEVEL_DEFAULT,
        RPC_C_IMP_LEVEL_IMPERSONATE, NULL, EOAC_NONE, NULL);
    if (SUCCEEDED(hResult))
    {
        // Create only one object on the local system
        hResult = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_WbemLocator, 0, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER,
            IID_IWbemLocator, (LPVOID*)&pLoc);

        if (SUCCEEDED(hResult))
        {
            // Connect to specific host system namespace
            hResult = pLoc->ConnectServer(TEXT(NETWORK_RESOURCE), NULL, NULL,
                0, NULL, 0, 0, &pSvc);
            if (SUCCEEDED(hResult))
            {
                /* Set the IWbemServices proxy
                * So the impersonation of the user will be occurred */
                hResult = CoSetProxyBlanket(pSvc, RPC_C_AUTHN_WINNT, RPC_C_AUTHZ_NONE,
                    NULL, RPC_C_AUTHN_LEVEL_CALL, RPC_C_IMP_LEVEL_IMPERSONATE,
                    NULL, EOAC_NONE);
                if (SUCCEEDED(hResult))
                {
                    /* Use the IWbemServices pointer to make requests of WMI
                    * For example, query for user account */
                    hResult = pSvc->ExecQuery(TEXT(WQL_LANGUAGE), TEXT(WQL_WIN32_USERACCOUNT_QUERY),
                        WBEM_FLAG_FORWARD_ONLY | WBEM_FLAG_RETURN_IMMEDIATELY, NULL, &pEnumerator);
                    if (SUCCEEDED(hResult))
                    {
                        // Go to get the next object from IEnumWbemClassObject
                        pEnumerator->Next(WBEM_INFINITE, 1, &pClsObject, &uReturn);
                        if (uReturn != 0)
                        {
                            // Get the value of the "sid, ..." property
                            pClsObject->Get(TEXT(WQL_SID), 0, &vtSID, 0, 0);
                            VariantClear(&vtSID);

                            // Print SID
                            wcout << vtSID.bstrVal;

                            pClsObject->Release();
                            pClsObject = NULL;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // Cleanup
    pSvc->Release();
    pLoc->Release();
    pEnumerator->Release();
    // Uninitialize COM library
    CoUninitialize();
```

This example does works properly!

Answer (score 1):

in cmd.exe

> whoami /user

if you need it programatically, please ask more specified

Comment: Questioner specifically asks for a C++ solution.

Comment: Fair enough, calling ```system("whoami /user");``` _is_ technically a C++ solution, and I should've specified I would like to do this through calling Windows API directly instead.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify what language you want. But if you're up for C# this article offers both the WMI method as well as a faster (while more verbose) method utilizing the Win32 API.

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/processownersid.aspx

I don't think there's currently another way of doing this without using WMI or the Win32 API.

Answer (score 0):

This one is the shortest of them all I believe.

```
UserPrincipal.Current.Sid;
```

Available with .net >= 3.5