# Adding Windows User Name to database

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, asp.net-mvc-3

ASP.NET MVC3 newb here.

I am working on a MVC3 intranet application that uses windows authentication. Windows auth is setup and ready to go no problem.

What I need to happen is to capture the username (Domain\first.last) whenever a user accesses the app for the first time and then store that information into a database and associate that name to a another unique identifier (numeric and auto-incremented).

I already found a way to get the username:

```
string user = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name;
```

What I am having an issue with is taking that variable and storing it in my database.

Any suggestions, hints, tips or nudges towards helpful resources are greatly appreciated.

Apologies if this scenario was posted elsewhere, if it was then I was unable to locate it.

Cheers Guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you are looking for here is really 'how to store some info in a database'
What database system?

Check out
http://www.datasprings.com/resources/articles-information/a-quick-guide-to-using-entity-framework

You can easily use the entity framework to store that value in the database which is what I think your question was really about.  I do agree with Bryanmac though, you should be storing the SID not the login name in case the name changes. If you know it will *NEVER* change then you could store the name, but since they can technically change in Windows, I'd be aware of this.
If you have a specific question then on how to store that field using the Entity Framework, please post that.

Comment: You are correct! I was trying to be detailed about the issue but oh well. Yeah, basically I wanted to find a way to map that information to the database. I will heed @bryanmac and your advice about using the sid as well as take a look at the link you posted. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

Be careful - user names and display names can change.  I would avoid storing them in the database.

Instead, look at storing the SID (id of the user).  The User property of the WindowsIdentity returns the SID.  You can store and update the user name for display purposes but don't rely on it for typing the authenticating user back to the previous user in your DB.

See this SO post as well:

[How can I get the SID of the current Windows account?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/251248/how-can-i-get-the-sid-of-the-current-windows-account)

Persist the SID (along with username for display only) and look up via SID.

Comment: Thanks @bryanmac! That really helps a lot. I think I should be able to accomplish what I need with what you and @Adam Tuliper posted. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

When you create your MVC3 application, there is an option for "Intranet Application" that has all of the Windows Authentication stuff working already, you might want to check that out and pull over pieces of the code for your current project (or migrate what you have depending on how far you are).

It has some special code placed into Web.Config as well as the extra files it creates.

Read more here:

http://weblogs.asp.net/gunnarpeipman/archive/2011/04/14/asp-net-mvc-3-intranet-application-template.aspx

and here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg703322%28VS.98%29.aspx

Also you'll want to use `User.Identity.Name` to reference the person viewing the website.